# --no-desktop and %U what for?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, arguments, file-manager

I want to know why is this argument so important when lauching nautilus or pcmanfm. What happens if i don't?

Also, i want to know what is the meaning of %U for:

```
Exec=pcmanfm %U
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an instance of Nautilus running behind the scenes that's managing your desktop, so when you run subsequent instances of Nautilus the `--no-desktop` is telling Nautilus not to try to manage the desktop icons etc.

The `%U` means to pass in a list of URLS:

```
%U   A list of URLs. Each URL is passed as a separate argument to the 
     executable program. Local files may either be passed as file: URLs 
     or as file path.
```

The rest of the list can be found here in the ["The Exec key section"](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.0.html#exec-variables) of the freedesktop.org documentation. Here are the rest.

*excerpt*

```
Code    Description
----    -----------
%f       A single file name, even if multiple files are selected. The system 
         reading the desktop entry should recognize that the program in 
         question cannot handle multiple file arguments, and it should 
         should probably spawn and execute multiple copies of a program 
         for each selected file if the program is not able to handle 
         additional file arguments. If files are not on the local file 
         system (i.e. are on HTTP or FTP locations), the files will be 
         copied to the local file system and %f will be expanded to point 
         at the temporary file. Used for programs that do not understand 
         the URL syntax.
%F       A list of files. Use for apps that can open several local files 
         at once. Each file is passed as a separate argument to the 
         executable program.
%u       A single URL. Local files may either be passed as file: URLs or 
         as file path.
%U       A list of URLs. Each URL is passed as a separate argument to the
         executable program. Local files may either be passed as file: URLs
         or as file path.
%d       Deprecated.
%D       Deprecated.
%n       Deprecated.
%N       Deprecated.
%i       The Icon key of the desktop entry expanded as two arguments, first 
         --icon and then the value of the Icon key. Should not expand to any 
         arguments if the Icon key is empty or missing.
%c       The translated name of the application as listed in the appropriate
         Name key in the desktop entry.
%k       The location of the desktop file as either a URI (if for example
         gotten from the vfolder system) or a local filename or empty if no 
         location is known.
%v       Deprecated.
%m       Deprecated.
```

Comment: so,even if i want to set PCMan-FM as mi default file manager, Nautilus is still running from backend?

Comment: what would happen if i run pcmanfm without `--no-desktop` argument?

Comment: @JGutierrezC - I believe so, I don't have first hand knowledge since I've always used GNOME but I would assume that if you're using GNOME that there is always at least one Nautilus running to manage the desktop components.

Comment: @JGutierrezC - if you've ever used Windows the exact same thing is going on there, where there is a single `Explorer.exe `running for the desktop.

Comment: @JGutierrezC - you could try the steps discussed in this thread: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=692238

Comment: Also [How to set PcManFm as the default file manager?](http://askubuntu.com/q/211325/25656)